# Merging same columns from a table with different conditions and counting specific field

Tags: sql-server

I want to retrieve data from one table but the data is based on conditions.

so now i've added the count section to my query but its not executing and the following error occured:

Column 'DailyStockHistory.Stc_Item_Desc' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

the query is :

```
Select 
    *
From 
(
    Select 
       dsh.Stc_Item_Desc, dsh.Imported_Date, dsh.Store_ID, dsh.Quantity_On_Hand,Count(inv.Sim_Network_Type) counterr
    From DailyStockHistory dsh,
    Temp_DailyInventory inv
    Where Stc_Item_Desc = 'SAWA/QuickNet prepaid triosim' 
        And dsh.Store_ID Like 'S%' 
        And (Imported_Date = '3-15-2017' Or Imported_Date = '3-22-2017')
) AS Data
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Quantity_On_Hand)
    FOR Imported_Date IN ([3-15-2017],[3-22-2017])
) AS PIVOTData
```

Comment: @csharpbd any help buddy ?

Comment: You are using aggregate function in the subquery. Add all the non aggregated column to a group by clause.

Comment: so how to solve it ? @GurV